# npm giving UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY

Tags: npm, amazon-ec2

I'm using Amazon Linux on AWS EC2, using npm version 1.3.6 and node version 0.10.42 (ancient, but upgrading is risky at the moment). It's worth noting that there is *no* proxy between this machine and the internet.

When running `npm install`, it's throwing me this error:

```
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/fibers/-/fibers-1.0.13.tgz
npm ERR! Error: UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY
npm ERR!     at SecurePair.<anonymous> (tls.js:1381:32)
npm ERR!     at SecurePair.emit (events.js:92:17)
npm ERR!     at SecurePair.maybeInitFinished (tls.js:980:10)
npm ERR!     at CleartextStream.read [as _read] (tls.js:472:13)
npm ERR!     at CleartextStream.Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:341:10)
npm ERR!     at EncryptedStream.write [as _write] (tls.js:369:25)
npm ERR!     at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:226:10)
npm ERR!     at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:216:5)
npm ERR!     at EncryptedStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:183:11)
npm ERR!     at write (_stream_readable.js:602:24)
npm ERR!     at flow (_stream_readable.js:611:7)
npm ERR!     at Socket.pipeOnReadable (_stream_readable.js:643:5)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 4.9.51-10.52.amzn1.x86_64
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /home/meteor-testing/Meteor_Server_Production/bundle/programs/server
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.42
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.6
```

It's not just the `fibers` package, it's all of the requests to `https://registry.npm.org` erroring out.

As far as I can tell, this error means that the certificate sent by the npm registry server could not be verified against the installed set of root certificates.

I searched around, and found this "solution":

```
npm config set strict-ssl false
```

This solves the immediate problem,  but makes package installations insecure.

A similarly bad alternative is:

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

This seems to work for some requests, but most of them (indirect dependencies maybe?) get rewritten to https anyway.

If I run

```
curl https://registry.npmjs.org/fibers/-/fibers-1.0.13.tgz
```

from this machine, it works fine. So maybe npm is using the wrong set of root certs? I can find out what `curl` is using:

```
curl -vv https://registry.npmjs.org/type-of/-/type-of-2.0.1.tgz >/dev/null
...
* Connected to registry.npmjs.org (104.16.23.35) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```

I did

```
yum update ca-certificates
```

to make sure that this file was up to date. Did not help.

So my next attempt was to point npm at this bundle too:

```
npm config set cafile /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```

But this does not help either; still getting the same error.

How to make npm work, without compromising security?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cafile` option was added later, and is not available in my version of npm. It only looks at the `ca` option, which is set to this by default:

```
npm config get ca
[ '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\nZNufy1Jf1r0ldEGeA+0ISck7s+xSh9rQD2Op\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n',
  '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\nX4XSQRjbgbMEHMUfpIBvFSDJ3gyICh3WZlXi/EjJKSZp4A==\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n',
  '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n',
  '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\nwFZUTKiL8IkyhtyTMr5NGvo1dbU=\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n' ]
```

I didn't check where this default came from, but I'm guessing it's hardcoded and rather outdated.

Okay, so let's just convert our system-wide CA bundle into a setting in [the format that `ca` expects](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#ca):

```
cat /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt | \
    awk 'cert { cert = cert "\\n" $0 }
         /-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----/ { cert = $0 }
         /-----END CERTIFICATE-----/ {
           printf "ca[] = \"%s\"\n", cert;
           cert = ""
         }'
    > ~/.npmrc
```

If it's stupid but it works, it ain't stupid.